# Do apps like Twitter implement custom relaunching when opened from background?

Tags: ios

I've noticed that when I go off an app like Snapchat, Twitter etc for a few seconds then go back on it, it opens from background as expected, on to the view controller I was last on. However, if I go off the app for more than a few minutes, when I tap on the app it loads the splash screen again and opens the home page.

I initially thought this was standard iOS behaviour, but when I installed my app onto my device I have noticed that even if I go off it for hours, when I come back onto it, the last view controller I was on is shown.

I have thought about checking how long the app was in background by saving times in NSUserDefaults, but don't actually know if this is the right way of going about achieving that kind of behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115244/how-long-ios-app-runs-in-background-in-average-until-its-killed

Comment: a better answer - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252239/do-ios-apps-run-in-the-background

Comment: @SamB Thanks for the links, but that doesn't explain why no matter how long my app is in the background, when I tap to open it simply lands back on the page I left it at.